# Using recursive function but what is my termination?

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to terminate my recursive function. As you can see in this picture below:

[image]

`getEmpty[9]` will return:

```
[6,10]
```

But I need it to return `[6,8,9,10,11]`

Because I want all the empties as long as it shares an edge with a previous empty box.

How to I terminate this recursion?

Currently I have

```
getEmpty(9)
        #my code here
        return empties;


empties = [6,10]
```

I added this:

```
for cell in empties:

        if(getEmpty(cell) not in empties):
            empties = empties+getEmpty(cell)
```

at the end, but it gives me an infinite loop that prints out:

```
[6,10]
[9]
```

non stop, how do I fix this?

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?

Comment: Why would 8 be included in the return set?  It doesn't share an edge with 9, nor with 9's neighbours 6 & 10.

Comment: shares edge with 11, and 11 share edge of 10, 10 share edge with 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

edit : sorry your question was very ambiguous. What you need is a simple graph traversal algorithm. here is a glimpse of it:

```
input : coordinate of a cell

function empty_cell_search(cell)
  for neighbor_cell in neighbors :
    if the_neighbor_cell is empty and is not already visited : 
      add the_neighbor_cell to set of visited cells
      union empty_cell_search(the_neighbor_cell) with current set of visited cells
  return the set of currently visited cells
```

Comment: are you saying `visited` is a list in your case?

Comment: the most simplest implementation will be a global set or a global list

Comment: and do you mean add those 2 list together into one list, when u say union them

Answer (score 1):

You should use this (python 3, but same idea for 2):

```
empty=[6,8,9,10,11]
start=9
done=[int(start)]
while True:
    complete=True
    for num0 in empty:
        for num1 in done:
            if (abs(num0-num1)==1 or abs(num1-num0)==3) and num0 not in done:
                complete=False
                done.append(num0)
    if complete=True:
         break
print(sorted(done))
```

Comment: May I ask why you are doing the abs value of num0 - num1?

Comment: this is sort of late, but it is testing whether it is off by one space or off by one row.